# Save PDF using CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I was unable to download PDF file which in page using casperjs. Here are my steps:

1. When we click the submit button after passing all input fields the page will load data in the format of grid within same page.
2. Above the grid we have images, If we click the the image, data will be loaded in to corresponding file format.

I am using CasperJS for clicks. Button click works perfectly but unable to click the image for downloading the file.

Here is my code:

```
casper.start().thenOpen("url", function() {
    console.log("keeneland divison by handle");

    casper.then(function(){
    this.echo(" Load page ");
    console.log("Setting Race Date :----------------"+casper.cli.get(0));
    casper.evaluate(function(inputRaceDate){
        console.log("Date :----------------"+inputRaceDate);
        document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_beginDate_I").value=inputRaceDate;
        aspxETextChanged('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_beginDate'); 
        document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_endDate_I").value=inputRaceDate;
        aspxETextChanged('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_endDate');
        document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cmbLocs_LBI0T0").value="All Locations";
        document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cmbTracks_I").value="All Tracks";
        document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlReportBy").value="0";
        /* document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlReportBy").value="1"; */
        /* document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlReportBy").value="2"; */
        document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit").click();
    });
});
});  
casper.then (function () {
        this.waitForSelector("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridExport_XLSPdf}",
        function pass () {
             this.echo(" pdf load ");
        document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridExport_XLSPdf').click()
        },
        function fail () {
       this.echo(" pdf load failed");
        },
        2000 // timeout limit in milliseconds
        );
});
```

I was unable to find the even ID in second step.